# Don't allow writing to a socket until an action completes

Tags: node.js, sockets, meteor

I have an asynchronous system where I want to execute a function completely until it is finished. I have the following function.

```
awaitOnceAsync(socket, successMessage, failMessage) {
  let listener;
  let timeoutId;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    listen = function () { /** waits for message */}
    this._sockets.get(socket).on('data', listen);
  }).then(() => {
    this._sockets.get(socket).removeListener('data', listen);
  });
}
```

The problem I am having is that I do not want the client to be able to write to this socket until the first promise is resolved.

How would one do this in Node?